# How do I have my sts show settings for spring boot language server?

Tags: java, sts

Here is what my sts 4.18 looks like

[image]

here is a screen shot from a sts issue.

[image]

How do I have my sts show those settings?

Comment: where originates that (second) screen shot? since i find *all* these (preference sections) under "Spring" (not "Language Servers...")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm confused by the second screenshot, since that's where I find all of these:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the Preferences dialog by clicking on **Window -> Preferences**.
2. In the search bar, type in **Language Servers**.
3. Select **Spring Boot Language Server** from the list of available language servers
4. The settings for the language server will be displayed in the right-hand
   pane. You can configure the settings as per your requirements.

Comment: It doesn't show.  Only thing you can do from 'language servers' is check/uncheck the enabled checkbox, you cannot select a server.  If you drill down to 'Spring Language Servers', all you see is the image the OP posted with the Logging field and checkbox.